# Unit test throws System.Security.SecurityException on call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, smtpclient

I have a class that has a method that returns an smtpclient to the caller. When called from the class itself it works fine, but when I call it from a unit test I get

```
Test Name:  SmtpTest
Test FullName:  WatchDogTests.UnitTest1.SmtpTest
Test Source:    REDACTED
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0778799

Result Message: 
Test method WatchDogTests.UnitTest1.SmtpTest threw exception: 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Initialize()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor(String host)
   at WatchDogV2.WatchDog.SetSmtp()
   at WatchDogTests.UnitTest1.SmtpTest()
```

The function looks like this

```
SmtpClient foo()
{
    SmtpClient temp = new SmtpClient("mysmtphost.com");
    temp.Port = 25;
    temp.UseDefaultCredentials = True;
    return temp;
}
```

The call within the unit test is as such

```
void UnitTest1()
{
    WatchDog Watcher = new WatchDog();
    SmtpClient temp = Watcher.foo();
   //Assert some stuff
}
```

I feel like the issue is that the unit tests are running at a lower trust level than the actual class, but I have not found a way to remedy this.

Update 1: Some more context as to how foo() is being used

```
void sendmsg(List<string> Message)
{
    SmtpClient client = foo():
    MailMessage msg = makemsg(Message);
    client.Send(msg);
}

SmtpClient foo()
{
    SmtpClient temp = new SmtpClient("mysmtphost.com");
    temp.Port = 25;
    temp.UseDefaultCredentials = True;
    return temp;
}

MailMessage makemsg(list<string> msg)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.to.add("recipient@host.com");
    mail.from = "sender@host.com";
    mail.body = msg; //In actuality a for loop that adds to the body
    mail.subject = "Watchdog report";
}
```

Comment: you probably don't want to actually connect to the smtp client in a unit test do you? don't you want to mock an smtp client instead?

Comment: I suppose so. I mostly want to check that the connection is setup properly within the function. Is there a way to sandbox my unit test so it connects to a mock client?

Comment: we'd have to see what your `Watcher` is doing to give you any insight there

Comment: In short, a series of function generate a message based on some calls to a sql server. This message is passed to a function that creates the smtpclient, creates the mailmessage, then sends the mail message via the smtpclient.

Comment: post the relevant code. are you using a mocking framework like Moq?

Comment: or post some of the assertions

Comment: I've posted some of the relevant code. I do not have a mocking framework, I am working in VS 2012.

Comment: can you post the kind of assertions you're making?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a mock client that you can use to verify the methods you're expecting to get called on an `SmtpClient` are in fact getting called.

Here's what it might look like with a mocking framework like Moq

```
var smtpMock = new Mock<SmtpClient>();
smtpMock.Setup(mock => mock.Send());

var watcher = new WatchDog();
watcher.Client = smtpMock.Object;

watcher.foo();

//verifies that the Send() method was called as expected
smptMock.Verify(mock => mock.Send(), Times.Once());
```

The reason you would want to mock the `SmtpClient` is that you only want to test that the methods you're expecting to be called get called. You can assume the `SmtpClient` is working as you would expect. So you fake or mock it and just check to see if the methods are being called as you expect them too.